# How to realize an empty element in a stack

Tags: java, stack, turing-machines

I want to implement a generic class called Tape for a Turing machine and I am not sure how to realize the blank parts of the tape. Till now it looks like:

```
public class Tape<T>{

private Stack<T> left  = new Stack<T>();   // left part of tape
private Stack<T> right = new Stack<T>();   // right part of tape
private T current;
private T BLANK = null;

public Tape(){
    right.push(BLANK);
    current = BLANK;
}
public void move(Direction direction) {
    if (direction == Direction.LEFT) {
        right.push(current);
        if (left.isEmpty()) left.push(BLANK);  // increase size of tape if necessary
        current = left.pop();
    } else if (direction == Direction.RIGHT) {
        left.push(current);
        if (right.isEmpty()) right.push(BLANK);  // increase size of tape if necessary
        current = right.pop();
    }
}
```

The main problem is, that I do not know how to handle this blank signal. Currently it is set to null, but at least since I want to call move and the stack is empty, push() and pop() wont work.

Any ideas how to mark blank since I do not know the type of T ?

Answer (score 0):

I would define BLANK in Tape's constructor.

```
private T BLANK;
private T current;
public Tape(T BLANK) {
    this.BLANK = BLANK;
    right.push(current = BLANK);
}
```

This way you can use whatever makes sense for BLANK, given your knowledge of your T type. For example:

```
new Tape<Integer>(null);
```

Or:

```
new Tape<String>(null);
```

Or even:

```
new Tape<String>("BLANK");
```

Try for example:

```
import java.util.Stack;

enum Direction {LEFT, RIGHT}

public class Tape<T>{

    private Stack<T> left  = new Stack<T>();   // left part of tape
    private Stack<T> right = new Stack<T>();   // right part of tape
    private T current;
    private T BLANK;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Tape<String>("BLANK").move(Direction.RIGHT);
    }

    public Tape(T BLANK){
        this.BLANK = BLANK;
        right.push(BLANK);
        current = BLANK;
    }
    public void move(Direction direction) {
        if (direction == Direction.LEFT) {
            right.push(current);
            if (left.isEmpty()) left.push(BLANK);  // increase size of tape if necessary
            current = left.pop();
        } else if (direction == Direction.RIGHT) {
            left.push(current);
            if (right.isEmpty()) right.push(BLANK);  // increase size of tape if necessary
            current = right.pop();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd look carefully at the Turing machine definition.  For example, using the wikipedia definition (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine), "The alphabet contains a special blank symbol", which suggests the type quantification should be constrained, for example, "Stack<T extends TuringSymbol>", with "TuringSymbol" having operation "TuringSymbol getBlank()".

Comment: But, is null a problem for push and pop?  I'm not seeing that these are a problem for Stack.  But, since Reads and Writes occur at arbitrary locations, is Stack the best type for your implementation?